# Why can't I return break? What should I use instead?

Tags: python, function, loops, break

How can I stop my loop from a function? Why can't I `return break`?

This is some sample code.

```py
def example():
    #a process goes here 
    return break
while 1:
    example()
```

I get an `invalid syntax` error.

Comment: What would `return break` even mean? You can `break` a loop or `return` from a function (the latter even inside a loop within the function), but not both.

Comment: Return a *value* (e.g. `True` or `False`) that can be checked inside the loop?

Comment: Simply put `break` right after the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have `example()` return a boolean to indicate that the loop should break:

```
def example():
    #a process goes here 
    return True # True to break / False to keep going
while True: # True is more explicit than 1
    if example():
        break
```

Note that in the particular example you gave, the loop could just be

```
while example():
    pass # Or whatever code goes afterwards
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to return break, you can just return from the loop based on the condition, as there is no way to return breaks in python :

```
def example():
  #a process goes here 
  return 
while 1:
  example()
```

Alternatively, you can set a variable which stores a value when it stops :

```
run = True
while run:
  # ...
  if condition is True:
      run = True
  else:
      run = False
      # ...
```